# Get foreign key unicode value in the template rather than its id

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, detailview

My model consists of `ForeignKey` and I am using `generics.DetailView` to render object detail in the django view.

MyModel

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myField = models.ForeignKey(...)

    def get_fields(self):
        # called by the template
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in type(self)._meta.fields]
```

MyView

```
class Detail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'path/to/template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # do something
        return context
```

And MyTemplate

```
{% for field, value in object.get_fields %}
           <tr>
               <th>{{ field }}</th>
               <td>{{ value }}</td>
           </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now when the template renders, what I get is `id` rather than `__unicode__` representation. Same problem is seen for the `ChoiceField` as well(I get value rather than their labels).

So my question is, how can I get label or unicode representation rather than their actual values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ForeignKeys, `getattr(self, field.name)` seems to be working. So:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myField = models.ForeignKey(...)

    def get_fields(self):
        # called by the template
        return [(field.verbose_name, unicode(getattr(self, field.name))) for field in type(self)._meta.fields]
```

For ChoiceFields, the label can be retrieved as `self.get_<field_name>_display()`. So, together, maybe something like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myField = models.ForeignKey(...)

    def get_field_value(self, field):
        if isinstance(field, models.CharField) and field.choices:
             return getattr(self, 'get_{}_display'.format(field.name))()
        return unicode(getattr(self, field.name))

    def get_fields(self):
        # called by the template
        return [(field.verbose_name, self.get_field_value(field)) for field in type(self)._meta.fields]
```